# C# How to set StructLayoutAttribute.Pack via Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, struct

I am creating a C# struct dynamically via reflection, and when I examine the struct's Type in my debugger I note that the [StructLayoutAttribute.Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack.aspx) is defaulting to 8. I would like to set the Pack to 1.

Essentially, I would like to do via reflection what can be done by adding this attribute to the declaration of a struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
```

I have tried using reflection after the type is created, but since the StructLayoutAttribute property has no Setter, it throws an exception.

My hunch is that it needs to happen in the call to ModuleBuilder.DefineType (where I am currently setting the LayoutKind, etc.), but I don't see any obvious corresponding [TypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Any pointers appreciated. Complete code for the class here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace AcmeCo.Serializable
{
    public class DynamicSimStructBuilder
    {

        private static Type structType;

        public static object GetStructInstance() {
            object ptInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(GetStruct(), new object[] { });
            return ptInstance;
        }

        public static Type GetStruct() {

            if (structType != null) {
               return structType; 
            }

            AppDomain myDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            AssemblyName myAsmName = new AssemblyName("MyDynamicAssembly");

            AssemblyBuilder myAsmBuilder =
               myDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(myAsmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

            ModuleBuilder structModule = myAsmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("StructModule", "MyDynamicAssembly.dll");

            TypeBuilder structTypeBld = structModule.DefineType("AcmeCo.ThirdPartyAPIWrapper.DyanmicStruct", TypeAttributes.Public |
                TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.SequentialLayout | 
                TypeAttributes.Serializable | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass, typeof(ValueType));

            // use a set of variables defined in an XML file to create Fields on the struct
            ThirdPartyAPIVariableCollection collection = ThirdPartyAPIVariableCollection.Deserialize();
            foreach (ThirdPartyAPIVariable variable in collection.ThirdPartyAPIVariables)
            {
                FieldBuilder field = structTypeBld.DefineField(variable.Name, Type.GetType(variable.SystemDataType, true) , FieldAttributes.Public);
            }

            // Base class and base class constructor.
            Type objType = Type.GetType("System.Object");
            ConstructorInfo objCtor = objType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });

            Type[] ctorParams = { };

            ConstructorBuilder pointCtor =
               structTypeBld.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public,
                                              CallingConventions.Standard, ctorParams);
            ILGenerator ctorIL = pointCtor.GetILGenerator();

            // Build the constructor. Begin by invoking the base class
            // constructor. The zero-index parameter of the constructor
            // is the new instance. Store the values of the fields.
            ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, objCtor);
            ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);


            // Create the type, and then create an instance of the type 
            // (or not, doesn't hurt to comment the CreateInstance line out...)
            Type ptType = structTypeBld.CreateType();

            object ptInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(ptType, new object[] { });

            DynamicSimStructBuilder.structType = ptType;
            int sizeOfNewData = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(ptType);
            Console.WriteLine("New type is: " + sizeOfNewData);

            // save the newly created type to a DLL for use later
            // (or not, doesn't hurt to comment the next line out...)
            myAsmBuilder.Save("MyDynamicAssembly.dll");

            return ptType;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like adding one more parameter lets you specify the packing size:

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyzw8bhy.aspx:

```
public TypeBuilder DefineType(
    string name,
    TypeAttributes attr,
    Type parent,
    PackingSize packsize
)
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. If only there were a "network" of "computers" where I could have looked that up.