# Setting PetaPoco TableName Attribute at Runtime

Tags: c#, sql, petapoco

I am trying to use petapoco to generate a table at runtime with a table name I specify but also use that table name to specify the TableName attribute of the model class.

The model would look something like this:

```
namespace Models
{
    public class Row
    {
        public string column1;
        public string column2;
    }
}
```

and the create statement would use the db.Execute function on a string defined in code with the table name being replaced by a dynamic value:

```
string sql = @"CREATE TABLE [StageGeneric](
                                [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                                [column1] [varchar](50) NULL,
                                [column2] [varchar](50) NULL,".Replace("StageGeneric", tableName);
```

So my question is, is the functionality built into petapoco to set the TableName attribute programmatically? Or would I have to do something like generate the model class at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I couldn't find exactly what I wanted. But I did find a work around. Creating the model class at runtime:
[C# How to set StructLayoutAttribute.Pack via Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673378/c-sharp-how-to-set-structlayoutattribute-pack-via-reflection)